# Using a generator to map a list and convert them to objects

Tags: python

I am working on generating navigation links.

Currently I have a list of dictionaries:

```
nav_objects = [
  {
    'href': "http://somedomain.com",
    'title': "Some Domain"
  },
  {
    'href': "http://somedomain2.com",
    'title': "Some Domain 2"
  },
  {
    'href': "http://somedomain3.com",
    'title': "Some Domain 3"
  }
  {
    'href': "http://somedomain4.com",
    'title': "Some Domain 4"
  }
]
```

I am currently using `map()` to loop this list and generate Navigation Links

```
def gen_nav_item(nav_item):
  return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(nav_item['href'], nav_item['title'])

nav_items = map(gen_nav_item, nav_objects)
```

This works as it generates a list of strings that I can print out later in my template. However I am curious if I could use a generator function instead, and whether this is good practice or not.
For instance.

```
def nav_item_generator(nav_objects):
  for nav_item in nav_items:
    yield '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(nav_item['href'], nav_item['title'])

nav_items = nav_item_generator(nav_objects)
```

Comment: You can do it. Where's your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could skip a special function entirely and just use a list comprehension or generator expression:

```
nav_items = ['<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(x['href'], x['title']) for x in nav_objects]
```

Change the outermost brackets to parentheses to make it a lazy genexpr instead of an eager listcomp.

By and large, if you need to write your own function to use `map`, you shouldn't use `map`; it will be slower and less Pythonic than using a listcomp or genexpr. `map` is only useful when there is an existing Python built-in that you can use directly.